# Can not edit only a part of my object in edit mode blender: 2.90.1

Tags: edit-mode

I am fairly new to blender, so please don't assume I have tried to do something that seems obvious to you.

Blender: 2.90.1

I am trying to make an airplane in blender, I am following a tutorial (its a two part tutorial, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4lsgMw9uQc) us the part I was on), when I go into edit mode, it allows me to edit almost any part of the object (there is one object and 3 empties, which are pictures), but it does not allow me to edit one specific part of the object. it allows me to select that part of the object using the face select and edge select, but for some reason not the vertex select, it also does not allow me move or resize that part of the object (I tried both with the shortcuts and with the side-bar), but it does let me delete.

Here is a picture of my blender in object mode:
[image: picture of my airplane on blender in object mode]

Here is a picture of my blender in edit mode with vertex select (the red circles are indicating the parts that are not select-able):
[image]

There is a reflection (I forgot the exact terminology), so whatever is edited on this side of the plane will be replicated onto the other side.

It is very probable that I pressed the wrong short-cut at the wrong time, I have done that many times, but I couldn't find a correction for this anywhere, so here I am.

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: if james_t's anwer does not answer, maybe try to unhide (Alt H), it looks like there's a bug in latest versions of Blender that make some parts unselectable

Comment: thank you SO much @moonboots, you sir are a legend

Comment: @MrZak, thank you, but that was not my problem, it was solved by moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide, it looks like there's a bug in latest versions of Blender that make some parts unselectable.

Answer (score 0):

while you may think there is one single object, I suspect there are child objects, expecially since your object is named Cylinder.002 (implying there might be other Cylinder objects.  Try expanding the Cylinder.002 object to reveal the children.

[image]

Be sure to exit the Edit mode of the parent before trying to select another object.

Also, you can recover File: Recover from a previous session or Auto Save.

Comment: It is a single object with a modifier, I will update the question with a picture of its contents, and yes, i will recover an older file if necessary, but I save rarely (not my brightest idea), so it is a worst case scenario situation.

Comment: my problem was solved by moonboots on a comment on the question, in case anyone is reading this and only read this part :D